# Hiding textarea resize handle in Safari

Tags: safari, webkit, css

I'm using textarea components in my application, and I control their height dynamically. As the user types, the height is increased whenever there is enough text. This works fine on IE, Firefox, and Safari.

However, in Safari, there is a "handle" tool in the lower right that allows user to resize the textarea by clicking and dragging. I also noticed this issue with the textarea in the stackoverflow Ask a Question page. This tool is confusing and basically gets in the way.

So, is there anyway to hide this resize handle?

(I'm not sure if "handle" is the right word, but I cannot think of a better term.)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can override the resize behaviour with CSS:

```
textarea
{
   resize: none;
}
```

or just simply

```
<textarea style="resize: none;">TEXT TEXT TEXT</textarea>
```

Valid properties are: both, horizontal, vertical, none

Comment: Not strictly relevant here, but Safari also respects the min-height, max-height, min-width, and max-width CSS properties to leave resizing enabled but place limits on how far it can resize.

Comment: What if I want to show it on hover after I've set resize:none ?

Comment: @Michael Forrest: have you tried textarea:hover { resize: inherit !important; } ? I have never tried it, just a guess.

Comment: One caveat: Not allowing the user to resize the `<textarea>` at all could be a usability issue. Setting `resize:vertical;` is often a better option. It shouldn't mess up your layout, and it gives the user a greater sense of control.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following CSS rule to disable this behavior for all `TextArea` elements:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

If you want to disable it for some (but not all) `TextArea` elements, you have a couple of options (thanks to [this page](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome/)).

To disable a specific `TextArea` with the `name` attribute set to `foo` (i.e., `<TextArea name="foo"></TextArea>`):

```
textarea[name=foo] {
    resize: none;
}
```

Or, using an ID (i.e., `<TextArea id="foo"></TextArea>`):

```
#foo {
    resize: none;
}
```

Note that this is only relevant for WebKit-based browsers (i.e., Safari and Chrome), which add the resize handle to `TextArea` controls.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override the resize behavior with CSS:

```
textarea
{
   resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the safari max-height max-width opportunity also works in firefox 4.0 (b3pre). good example here by the way: http://www.alanedwardes.com/posts/safari-and-resizable-textboxes/