# How to disable multiline input being dynamically resized by user?

Tags: html, browser, input

I have a multiline input on my html form and some browsers (firefox 4 and chrome) allow users to resize it dynamically. It is nice, but it breaks my layout. Is it possible to disable this feature?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding textarea resize handle in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/hiding-textarea-resize-handle-in-safari)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If users resize the field, it's probably because they want *(or need)* it to be bigger <sup>1</sup>.

In such a case, you should consider your users know what they are doing, are doing it because they want / need to, and that they will accept the layout to be a little *broken*, provided it allows them to use that textarea.

Still, if you want to do that *(you shouldn't)*, quoting [How do I disable textarea resizing?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5f9cd62207e2c7a8&hl=en) :

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>I don't see very well, and when I zoom, or make something *bigger*, it's because I need too -- and, in such a case, I prefer a layout a bit broken to a website I cannot use !</sub>

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I understand that, probably I will not use that, asked in case it will be really necessary.

Comment: in both chrome and FF, once the user resizes a text element, you can't resize it later with javascript. sometimes this can break more than layout in a dynamic webapp. i agree that this is usually a bad idea, but there are cases where it is necessary

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS:

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

See [`resize` property @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/resize).

A better solution, however, is to fix your layout so that resizing the textarea doesn't break the layout (at least for reasonable amounts of resizing). Depending on just how, and how badly, it breaks the layout, users might not event mind it. The typical web user will probably never even notice the little resize handle anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, add this:
`textarea {
    resize: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't disable that. But it can't possibly break your layout until the user takes action, <s>and you can't prevent that anyway</s>.