# Is it possible to disable textarea's multiline option?

Tags: html, textarea

Of course, I can use standard html text box, but I need text area for some reason.

So, is it possible to disable textarea's multiline option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424001/how-to-disable-multiline-input-being-dynamically-resized-by-user

Answer (score 22):

You can set the size of your textarea using the `cols` and `rows` attributes and make it non-resizable in CSS but you can't prevent the user from adding more than one line. Even if the area is just too small, a scrollbar will appear and let them write as many lines as they want.

If you really need to get just one line, I suggest setting the `rows` attribute to 1 and checking if the input has a single line with Javascript.

In html:

```
<textarea name="a"  cols="5" rows="1" ></textarea>
```

In CSS:

```
textarea{
    resize: none; 
    #You can use resize: horizontal if you just want to disable vertical resize
}
```

Still, I'd suggest using an `<input type="text" ... />` Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: This might not be the OP's use case, but I've just run into this issue when building a basic rich single-line input (allows for styling of certain words or word groups within the textbox). To achieve this, I've overlaid a styled div with `pointer-events:none;`. To keep it in sync with the input on scroll (when the user types beyond the edge), you need to listen for a scroll event. Unfortunately, only a textarea will fire one (input refuses to). So in this case, input must be avoided.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu how so? The fiddle you linked to seems to work exactly the way I described. At least in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see that you mentioned the user is still able to create a new line in the textarea. Me, and I think also the OP, was looking for a solution to prevent also that.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu the solution for that is `type="text"` :)

Comment: @toniedzwiedz actually, the solution is JS :)

Answer (score 15):

You can keep all the text on a single line by settings `rows="1"` on the `<textarea>`, like the other answers have suggested, and then applying the following CSS to the text area:

```
resize: none;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

This CSS will prevent the single row from wrapping, while still making the keeping the whole line visible by providing a scroll bar to navigate any text that overflows the visible area.

Comment: Warning: Even while having `white-space: nowrap` will make it display everything on 1 line (`rows="1"` or otherwise), it still takes all characters user might enter in the textbox including carriage returns that are not being displayed.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible using `input` event to remove all new-line characters every time a user inputs something.

```html
<textarea oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/\n/g,'')"></textarea>
```

Or in a more civilized way:

**html**

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

**js**

```js
document.getElementById('ta').addEventListener('input', function(e){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\n/g,'')
});
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qrnv6sz/)

Comment: Only solution in the list that worked for me

Comment: For replacing the part after the first linefeed, you can do `oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/\n[\s\S]*/,'');update()"`, where `[\s\S]` is like `.` but it matches newlines. The `//s` modifier also makes dot match newlines, but it was only added in ES2018.

Comment: do I need to consider `\r\n` or is new lines in browsers always `\n`?

Comment: @Loligans `\r\n` should not appear with a standard keyboard typing, unless someone's copy-paste it. Anyway, it is a good practice to get rid of the `\r` as well. Integrating `\r` in Windows, was one of Microsoft's biggest mistakes, to see until these days a lot of suffering in IT field.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `wrap="off"` attribute in textarea to be displayed in a single line.

```html
<textarea wrap="off"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this pure JS code and it will not allow user to enter multiple lines in textarea

```
var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];//your desired TextArea
textArea.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { e.preventDefault(); }
};
```

**NOTE:** This method will not work if user copies a multi line text and pastes it in the TextArea.

Answer (score 1):

Use rows=1 to display only 1 line. you can get further more information from this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Comment: Main use of testarea is to have multiple line of data if you want single line then use textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `rows` attribute to 1.

It is not possible to disable the multiline

Answer (score -2):

The following jQuery snippet forces textarea to be displayed in a single line.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(){$(this).attr('rows', 1);});
  });
```