# JSON is invalid when I take the value from HTML textarea when the user inputs text with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have this json format of

```
{
   questionID: int
   studentAnswer: "String"
}
```

The studentAnswer field is populated from whatever is inputted in an HTML textarea. If I input something in one line only, the json is valid. But if I input something where i press enter to go to the next line, the json becomes invalid. I need the studentAnswer to be able to hold the input value with multiple lines. How can I fix this?

Comment: JSON requires that the keys be quoted.

Comment: Show your code. Show how you're calling `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that multiline json's aren't valid. Since you're using a textarea, perhaps you can resize the textarea, restrict it, sanitize its inputs, or change the form type.

Ultimately, you want whatever the user input to be one line. Try this option out:

[Is it possible to disable textarea's multiline option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732446/is-it-possible-to-disable-textareas-multiline-option)

Comment: If he calls `JSON.stringify()` it will convert the newlines to `\n` escape sequences, which are valid.

Comment: But I need the user to be able to input multiple lines, since the textarea is for the user to enter python code to answer the question :(

Comment: @Barmar Good point. I just assumed that he was doing it literally, which led to the wonky multiline json.

Comment: @Raizuri That's why you should never create JSON by hand, always use library functions, they do the right thing.