# Neatest (and fast) way to remove top lines from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a webpage that displays last `1000` lines of a logfile then updates via AJAX every `x` seconds loading new content (if any) and appending to textarea with `$('#log').append(new_data)`, a sort of `tail -f`.

The problems come up after some time when too many lines are appended and the page becomes slow or unresponsive.

So I'd like to limit number of lines to, say, 5000 so it means I should:

- retrieve `new_data`
- calculate `overflow = 5000 - lines_ in_new_data - lines_in_textarea`
- if `overflow > 0` remove first `overflow` lines from textarea
- append new_data to textarea

In my mind this involves one or more `split('\n')` of both `textarea` and `new_data` values then use array lengths and slicing but I guess if there's a neater or better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Textareas don't actually display `'\n'` as a line break, though. Is the textarea resizable? It will be much simpler if you limit to a number of characters rather than a number of lines.

Comment: upvote for using character length rather than number of lines.

Comment: I understand it would be much simpler but I'd like to get the page working, as much as possible, in a _linuxish_ line-based way. It's a log after all... Even if with some workaround this could be easily avoided it would be really ugly having first line of textarea truncated...

Comment: @Matt: no, it's not resizable, just a plain textarea 80cols x 24rows

Comment: If the textarea is limited to 80 columns, what happens when a log line contains more than 80 characters? Does it wrap to the next line, or overflow the width? When you want to remove extra lines, do you want to count the extra characters as part of a single line? BTW, some browsers will allow any textarea to be resized with a handle unless you [explicitly disable it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/).

Comment: @Matt: normally lines wrap to next line but it _should_ keep on counting 1 line. I know about browser textarea handles as I'm a Chrome user and find it useful and **not** to be disabled. As I'm understanding the concept of _number of lines_ in a textarea is tied with wraps too, thing that makes things harder...

Comment: Okay, so when you want to remove lines, you basically want to ignore wrapped lines - that is, lines are separated only by `'\n'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use a single `split` and then `join` after truncating the data, something like this:

```
// on data retrieved
var total = ((textarea.value 
              ? textarea.value + "\n" 
              : "") 
          + new_data).split("\n");

if (total.length > 10) 
    total = total.slice(total.length - 10);

textarea.value = total.join("\n");
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ArvQ7/** (cut to 10 lines for brevity)

Comment: +1, I definitely like your strategy of using a timestamp so that it's really easy to see the sliding window.

Comment: you may want to change `textarea.value = total.join("\n")` to `textarea.val(total.join("\n"))` to run code with jQuery.

Comment: @neurino: yeah, you can but I prefer to map straight to the DOM property rather than using jQuery's accessor methods.  It's slightly more efficient :-)  It would be `textarea[0].value` if `textarea` is a jQuery object.

Comment: @Andy: does mapping straight to DOM ensures same cross-browser compatibility?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (demo linked below is probably more useful):

#### HTML

```
<button id="clickme">More lines</button>
<br/>
<textarea id="log" rows="24" cols="80"></textarea>
<p>Lines: <span id="numLines">0</span></p>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var $log = $('#log'),
    $button = $('#clickme'),
    $numLines = $('#numLines'),
    MAX_LINES = 5000,
    lorem_ipsum = ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    lineCounter = 0;

$button.click(function()
{
    $log.val($log.val() + generateMoreLines()).change();
});

$log.change(function ()
{
    var text = tail(MAX_LINES, $log.val());
    $log.val(text);
    $numLines.text(countNewlines(text));
});

function generateMoreLines()
{
    var buf = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        buf.push(lineCounter++ + lorem_ipsum);
    }
    return buf.join('\n');
}

function countNewlines(haystack)
{
    return count('\n', haystack);
}

function count(needle, haystack)
{
    var num = 0,
        len = haystack.length;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) === needle)
        {
             num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

function tail(limit, haystack)
{
    var lines = countNewlines(haystack) + 1;
    if (lines > limit)
    {
        return haystack
            .split('\n')
            .slice(-limit)
            .join('\n');
    }
    return haystack;
}
```

The newline handling isn't perfect (do you count all occurrences of `'\n'`? What if the string starts or ends with `'\n'`? etc.).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/3ghjm/

Comment: Thanks, it just need a newline when appending new content. Since content comes from a logfile string always starts and ends without `\n` (I fetch content using a call to `tail -n 1000` first time then remembering file position and using `seek` on sequent calls).