# make the user can't control the size of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding textarea resize handle in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/hiding-textarea-resize-handle-in-safari)

in textarea input the user can change the size of the input area how to make him can't do that,if it is no possible ,then how i can make the text input field add new line,that is when the user add to the end of the text field a new line entered and the size of the text field increase

Comment: Only Chrome allows you to resize the textarea, as far as I know.

Comment: @JohnP Firefox 4.0 also allows you to resize a textarea

Comment: @kevin you're absolutely right. Can't believe I didn't notice it!

Comment: From a usability point of view I'd have to say to leave this to the user. It's similar to disabling the right click functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

*Source: [Google(disable textarea resize)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=disable%20textarea%20resize)*

Comment: thanx a lot but one more thing how to make it enlarge while user adding new line that is when the user add new line the text area add new row ,if i should us javascript i will do it but if there is another way simple tell me thx

Comment: @sam: That's a separate question. Create a new question for that.