# <textarea> expands and destroys table formatting

Tags: html, css, format, textarea

Is there a way to constrict how far a `<textarea>` can expand? Or a way to format a `<table>` so that it doesn't look bad when you expand a `<textarea>`?

Comment: How is the `textarea` being expanded?

Comment: By clicking on the lower right corner of the <textarea> and pulling it out. Exactly like this <textarea> that I typed in to answer your question.

Comment: You might want to prevent it from being resized?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/hiding-textarea-resize-handle-in-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know is with the resize css property.  It is a CSS3 property so it may not help you if you are dealing with older browsers. 
Try applying this class to your text areas...

```
.noresize{
    resize:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-height` and `max-width` for the style of textarea. This will prevent the textarea to be expandable.

Note: IE doesn't know `max-width` and `max-height`. but you can do something like this:

```
textarea{ 
   width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 776 ? "777px" : "auto" ); /* sets max-width for IE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want resizing completely then put a "resize:none;" style attribute on the textarea. If you want resizing in a controlled way then add something like max-width: 300px;
max-height: 250px; to the text area style.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
    resize: vertical;
    width: 350px;
    min-height: 80px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Using this code, the user can resize the textarea vertically. Applying max- and min-height prevents the layout from breaking.