# Remove the default settings for text boxes in google chrome and safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I have used < textarea > tag , it was working fine with IE and firefox but not with safari and chrome, when user gets focus on < textarea > tag, Chrome highlights the box with yellow color, after reffering some previous posts I found these

```
 style="outline:none"
```

Then it removed the yellow color highliting to the text box but still to the right bottom corner of the text box i see diagonally passed three lines , they look so small , this is so frustrating , How do i make them disapper

http://d3pr5r64n04s3o.cloudfront.net/tuts/195_bootstrap/tut/input_textarea.png see these link for the image how it looks like, I want that right bottom corened lines to disappear in chrome and safari, how do i do that?

Comment: That's the resize handle. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/hiding-textarea-resize-handle-in-safari

Comment: ah! but i use elastic function for these <textarea> tag it increases it height based on input of user , sorry i could not try right now becuase my pages are at my home and now im in office of juery text box will it increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari) now support the resize property by default on some elements like textarea. To get rid of the knurling on the bottom-right corner, you should add:

```
resize: none;
```

in your CSS style. This will also disable users' ability to resize the textarea.

Comment: I have to mention that my text box uses elastic function of jquery that increases its height based on input and resize:none effect this property?

Comment: hey could you tell me what do you mean by webkit browsers, how many divisions we have ? and what for what are the standards they follow please could you post some link your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: By Webkit browser I mean any Web browser that uses Webkit as its layout engine. The two most common are Apple Safari and Google Chrome, but since it is open source anyone can essentially use Webkit in their own custom browser. The point is that content will be rendered exactly the same in these browsers which is why some people simply refer to them as Webkit browsers rather than Safari or Chrome or any other browser which may be utilizing Webkit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

Comment: This will not affect the AutoResize jQuery plugin, if that's the one you're describing. See a demo here: http://www.azoffdesign.com/autoresize -- it's using resize: none; as well.