# how to forbid resizing of TextArea.For in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable resizable property of TextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-to-disable-resizable-property-of-textarea)

i want to disable using of resizing in TextArea.For in my webapplication.
in google chrome and other browser its looks terrible.
how can i do it?

Comment: What does it mean of "disable using of resizing in TextArea"?

Comment: textarea
    {
       resize: none;
    }

[See this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/hiding-textarea-resize-handle-in-safari

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the browsers ability to resize textareas, use the following css:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```