# How to restrain text-area sizes?

Tags: html

I have a textbox, but when the user makes the box bigger, it breaks the layout.

I tried using max-length, but it still doesn't work.

How can I remove the option to make the size bigger?

Comment: try `max-width` and `max-height` instead.

Comment: I believe you are looking for an option to prevent the user from resizing textareas. It's not possible with HTML alone, you'll need CSS: `textarea { resize: none; }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding textarea resize handle in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588089/hiding-textarea-resize-handle-in-safari) (Note that the solution isn't Safari dependent)

Answer (score 1):

In css add:

```
max-width: 200px;
```

Or like this

```
<textarea style="max-width: 200px;"></textarea>
```

Edit:

Or you can also hide the resize feature by using:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

You can also decide to resize your textareas only horizontal or vertical, this way:

```
textarea { resize:vertical; }

textarea { resize:horizontal; }
```

Comment: How could I hide the two little lines in the corner?

Comment: Just add to the textarea **style="resize: none;"**

Comment: Would this be cross-browser compatable?